# Random Forest Accuracy Difference between Test Data & New Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I experience huge difference in my Random Forest model performance between test data & new data.

Objective of my model is to forecast future period stock returns based on time series data on the same stock.  I applied Random Forest Classifier using scikit-learn in Python to predict return decile instead of the actual price change. I used data up to June 2017 and trained the model on 80% of data and tested it on 20%.  The results were great.  Probability of mis-classification greater or smaller than 1 decile was 3%.  That means if model predicts return to fall in Decile 5, actual return would fall below Decile 4 or above Decile 6 in only 3% of cases. I was very happy with that.

However when I applied the model on "new data", from July 1, 2017 to the present, I got horrific results.  Probability of mis-classification >+/-1 decile jumped to 60%!!!

I thought issue was over-fitting due to depth of trees.  But it was not.  I set up  min_samples_leaf to 20 and even 40 and actually it made forecasts on new data worse.

What else could it be?  If the model does so well on historical test data, why it does so differently on the new data. The nature of new data cannot be that different.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what stocks you are looking at but the assertion: 'The nature of new data cannot be that different' is generally wrong with stocks, where the market changes so dynamically over time it is very hard to infer much from the past about the future at an individual stock level. 

'Past performance is not a guide to the future' is plastered all over most financial product prospectuses for a reason.

Comment: I hear you, but without going into Efficient Market Hypothesis discussion, the model did show huge promise on the test of 20% of historical data withheld from training.  The difference between test data and new data should not be material to cause en epic fail???  Something else is missing here...

Comment: Again very hard to say without knowing what stocks you are looking at (would help if you share some), but there are plenty of distributions of stock prices where training data sets would perform well and future predictions utterly terrible: Horse carriage companies pre 1920, lake ice exporters pre 1930, punch card computer makers pre 1960s and so on and so on.

Answer (score 3):

That's a wide question and there may be many reasons for the worse performance on new data, but I'll try to help you a bit:

1. Overfitting - check RF scores on training data and test data separately -> if the difference is huge and you have a super small error on training set and a significant one on test data - then your model probably has an overfitting problem.
2. Try to add some of the new data to the model (i.e. next 6 months, leaving the other 6 to verify). If the model performs much better, then maybe there's an underlying fundamental factor to the price, i.e. something that caused prices to change their behaviour after July 2017.
3. Features and feature engineering - that's connected to the previous point, but there may be something you're missing and that's not really taken into account in historical data. For example, for some time now the energy prices in europe rise and one of the reasons for it seems to be a rise in carbon prices. That's something that wasn't taken into account before and 'emerged' in 2018 and I believe it wasn't a model feature for analysts until recently. That may also be the case for you -> maybe something big happened or there's a feature that has to be added so it works in 2018.

Comment: Re#1 I ruled out over-fitting based on having 200 trees and shorting the trees to 20 and 40 samples, as stated in my original posting.  Am I missing something?  What else could cause potentially cause over-fitting? Re #2 My features are predominantly quantitative indicators based on price and volume behavior (i.e. technical analysis).  If they worked well based on training & testing on 20 years of historical data, hard to believe they fail so miserably in the last 12 moths?

Comment: #1 I'd try using `min_samples_leaf` > 50, at least that's usually the starting point for my models: "smaller leaf makes the model more prone to capturing noise in train data. Generally I prefer a minimum leaf size of more than 50."
How is your training accuracy compared to test accuracy?
#2 it's pretty hard to tell without knowing the problem better :(